# How to select all body elements except first div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="switcher" class="switcher">
        <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
        <button id="switcher-default">
                Default
        </button>
        <button id="switcher-narrow">
            Narrow Column
        </button>
        <button id="switcher-large">
            Large Print
        </button>
    </div>
    <p>asdfasdfasdfas dsadf</p>
    <p>asd'lfkasdf</p>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want to add a class to all body elements except my first `div` (which has the `id` called switcher), when I click on the Large print `button`.

I have tried

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#switcher-large").bind("click", function(){       
    $("body:not(:first-child)").addClass("large");      
    });
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#switcher-large").bind("click", function(){       
    $("body:not(div)").addClass("large");       
    });
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#switcher-large").bind("click", function(){       
        $("body").not("#switcher").addClass("large");       
        });
    });
```

but none seem to work (the class applies to all elements).

I don't want to find an alternate way like selecting only `p` elements. I just want to understand why the selectors I used don't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to exclude the `document.body` itself. Like

```
$("body *").not("#switcher").addClass("large");
```

This will query for all children of `body`, excluding `#switcher`. Maybe more convinient:

```
$(document.body).contents().not('#switcher').addClass('large');
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It works using the contents method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").children().not("#switcher").addClass("large");
```